# MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during command execution . Asp.net Core

Tags: mysql, asp.net-core

When trying to register a new user in the project, an error is occurring on these lines:

`WebApplication3.MyClass.ConDB.GetData(string _sqlCommand)` in **ConDB.cs:**

```
adapter.Fill(dt);
```

**AND**

```
WebApplication3.Controllers.AccountController.Register(
string username, string phone, string email, 
string password, string confirmPassword)
```

in **AccountController.cs:**

```
DataTable dt = conDB.GetData($"INSERT INTO 
   `user`(`Email`, `UserName`, `Phone`, `Password`, `ProfilePath`) VALUES 
    ('{email}','{username}','{phone}','{encode_password}', '{userDataPath}');");
```

**This is the error:**

```
An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)

MySqlException: Reading from the stream has failed.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()

MySqlException: Fatal error encountered attempting to read the resultset.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlDataReader.NextResult()

MySqlException: Fatal error encountered during command execution.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)

EndOfStreamException: Attempted to read past the end of the stream.
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.ReadFully(Stream stream, byte[] buffer, int offset, int count)
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlStream.LoadPacket()
```

**This is the code:**

```
WebApplication3.MyClass.ConDB.GetData(string _sqlCommand) in ConDB.cs

public DataTable GetData(string _sqlCommand)
{
  MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand(_sqlCommand, myConnection);
  MySqlDataAdapter adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter(command);
  DataTable dt = new DataTable();
  adapter.Fill(dt);
  return dt;
 }
public void ExecuteQuery(string _sqlCommand)
  {
    MySqlCommand command = new MySqlCommand("", myConnection);

    WebApplication3.Controllers.AccountController.Register(string username, string phone, string email, string password, string confirmPassword) in AccountController.cs

   string userDataPath = profile_path + email.Split('@')[0] + "_" + email.Split('@')[1].Split('.')[0];
   Helper.DirectoryCopy(default_profile_path, userDataPath, true);
   initDriver(userDataPath);
   driver.Navigate().GoToUrl(homeURL);
   DataTable dt = conDB.GetData($"INSERT INTO `user`(`Email`, `UserName`, `Phone`, `Password`, `ProfilePath`) VALUES ('{email}','{username}','{phone}','{encode_password}', '{userDataPath}');");

  HttpContext.Session.SetString("login", "1");
  HttpContext.Session.SetString("email", email);
  return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
}
  else
```

Can anyone help me in this problem?

Comment: Thank you so much for your attention. Your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Use `ExecuteNonQuery()` instead because you are not looking for a datatable in return while inserting a record. ExecuteNonQuery() would return you the number of rows affected.

It is possible to achieve the same using MySqlDataAdapter, but for inserting one record it is not worth the effort

Reference: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/dev/connector-net/8.0/html/M_MySql_Data_MySqlClient_MySqlCommand_ExecuteNonQuery.htm